Ubuntu port forwarding
I am trying to get port forwarding to work on my ubuntu desktop computer. I have previously successfully managed to forward ports from my router, to other computers on this network so I don't think it is a router problem, and I have a public static IP which is hosting my server.
Currently, I am trying to forward a randomly selected port: 58970 to my ubuntu machine which is on ip 192.168.0.174
(base) tue@tue-ubuntu:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:c0:4d:db:fd:d1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp4s0
    inet 192.168.0.174/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eno1
       valid_lft 2985sec preferred_lft 2985sec
    inet6 2a06:4006:2033:0:3e:f9fc:11ff:8478/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 3883sec preferred_lft 2883sec
    inet6 2a06:4006:2033:0:e40c:8b84:fe3a:da6b/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 3883sec preferred_lft 2883sec
    inet6 fe80::a646:62fd:198a:6378/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether bc:17:b8:c0:bd:b8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: br-3b5806c4ad15: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:0b:84:44:d0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-3b5806c4ad15
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:bff:fe84:44d0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:d1:4c:de:b7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: veth7fc3c63@if6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-3b5806c4ad15 state UP group default 
    link/ether 1e:f4:aa:af:bf:4b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::1cf4:aaff:feaf:bf4b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

I initially had ufw disabled, but I figured I might need that for the port forwarding to work and tried to follow this guide: https://99rdp.com/how-to-open-a-port-in-ubuntu-20-04/
So basically I enabled ufw and added the ports to ufw, so now I have:
(base) tue@tue-ubuntu:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
58970                      ALLOW       Anywhere                  
51036                      ALLOW       Anywhere                  
58970 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
51036 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)    

     

However the port does not show up when I use netstat as suggested:
(base) tue@tue-ubuntu:~$ netstat -lntu
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:29754         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17500           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17603         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17600         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::17500                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:3350                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::3389                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17500           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33266           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::33156                :::*                               
udp6       0      0 fe80::a646:62fd:198:546 :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*  

                         

And if I go to https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ and enter my public ip address and the port it also tells me that the port is closed.
Does anyone have good ideas for what my next step should be or how I should troubleshoot this?

You need an actual service to listen on that port.  Refer to my answer here to better understand what netstat actually shows and what you don't actually have here.  And to clear up the misunderstanding of opening a port in the firewall and actually having a service listen on that port.

Yeah that makes a lot of sense, thank you

Your netstat output shows that there is no service listening for a connection on port 58970.
No listener = Port closed.
